# tackle class imbalance in single shot object detector

Tags: ios, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am training an **object detection** model for multi-class objects in the image. The dataset is custom collected and labelled data with bounding boxes and class labels in the ground truth data.

I trained the **MobileNet+SSD** , **SqueezeDet** and **YoloV3** networks with this custom data but get poor results. The rationale of choosing these models is their fast performance and light weight (low memory foot print). Their single shot detector approach is shown to perform well in literature as well.

The class instance distribution in the dataset is as below

- Class 1  --  2469
- Class 2  --  5660
- Class 3  --  7614
- Class 4  --  13253
- Class 5  --  35262

Each image can have objects from any of the five classes. Class 4 and 5 have very high incidence.

The performance is very skewed with high recall scores and Average Precision for the class 4 and 5 ,  and an order of magnitude difference (lower) for the other 3 classes.

I have tried fine tuning on different filtering parameters , NMS threshold, model training parameters to no avail.

**Question,**

**How to tackle such class imbalance to boost the detection Average precision and object detection accuracy for all classes in object detection models. ?**

Answer (score 0):

- Low precision means your model is suffering from false positives. So you can try **hard negative mining**. Run your model. Find False positives. Include them in your training data. You can even try using only false negatives as false examples.
- As you expect another way can be **collecting more data** if possible.
- If it is not possible you may consider **adding synthetic data**. (i.e. change brightness of image, or view point(multiply with a matrix so it looks stretched))
- One last thing may be having data for each class i.e. 5k for each.

PS: Keep in mind that flexibility of your model has a great impact. So be aware of over fitting under fitting.

Comment: Changing perspective will not work , as the objects of interest are dense and small. The texture outlook shares some overlap between classes too. 3) Adding synthetic with image brightness etc. changed should cause problem as it is the same image repeated example in the training set. 4) reducing classes to 5k will potentially limit the training performance regardless. will try out hard negative mining.  Is there a way to address in the loss function ?

Answer (score 0):

In generating your synthetic data as mentioned by previous author, do not apply illumination or viewpoint variations..etc to all your dataset but rather, randomly. The number of classes is also way off, and will be best to either limit the numbers or gather more datasets for those classes. You could also try applying class weights to penalize the over representing classes more. You are making alot of assumptions that simple experimentation will yield results that could surprise you. Remember deep learning is part science and alot of art.